# Question about the wavefunctions of a system of non-identical fermions

Tags: wavefunction, nuclear-physics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, isospin-symmetry

If one interchanges two *identical* fermions in the wavefunction of a $N$-particle system, the total wavefunction changes by a sign i.e., the total wavefunction should be antisymmetric under the interchange of any two *identical* fermions. I have two very related doubts regarding the application of this principle.

**DEUTERON**

Deuteron is a bound state of a neutron and a proton. It is made of two non-identical fermions - the proton which is electrically charged and the electrically neutral neutron. Why should we insist that the total wavefunction (space $\times$ spin $\times$ isospin) be antisymmetric under the interchange of $n$ and $p$?

**Note added in response to @naturallyinconsistent** Well, one may argue that n and p are two different isospin states of the same particle "the nucleon". So with isospin symmetry, $n$ and $p$ may be considered identical (See the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4778/164488) by Lubos). But isospin symmetry is a good symmetry only if we can neglect the electric charge of the proton i.e. in a Universe governed only by strong interactions but not electromagnetism. In the real world, n and p are distinguished by their electromagnetic interactions.

**BARYON**

Similarly, consider a light baryon that is made of three different flavors of quarks $u,d,s$ which, as I understand, are non-identical fermions. Because the charge of $u$ is not equal to the charge of $d,s$. The mass of $u,d$ is approximately equal but not equal to that of $s$. Therefore, how can we claim that the total wavefunction (space $\times$ spin $\times$ isospin $\times$ color) will be antisymmetric under the interchange of any two quarks?  It seems to me that the antisymmetry of the total wavefunction is at best an approximate requirement in the limit when mass differences can be neglected and differences in the electric charges can be neglected.

Comment: where did you get the impression that the non-identical fermions are also anti-symmetrised?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I gave you two examples. The deuteron and the baryons. If you cared to read it, you'll understand that the question is precisely that. Why should the deuteron wavefunction be completely antisymmetric (when n and p are not identical)?

Comment: I'm precisely asking you who gave you that idea that those non-identical fermions are supposed to be skew-symmetrised?

Comment: Why is deuteron wavefunction completely antisymmetric? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4778/164488   Why are baryon wavefunctions completely antisymmetric? Also see https://students.iiserkol.ac.in/~mms15ms051/courses/PH4204/[Pal%20Palash%20B]%20An%20Introductory%20Course%20of%20Particle%20Physics.pdf Page 215, Example 2

Comment: You should add these things to the question, because otherwise it is not easy to understand where you are coming from. What part of the answer given by Lubos do you not understand? While they are definitely not identical fermions on the fundamental level, the trick is to consider them as nucleons under isospin, in which case they are supposed to be identical under this scheme.

Comment: I think I have explained that too. When electric charges are present, I think isospin symmetry cannot be exact. The particles can be distinguished by their EM interactions. In a Universe governed only by strong interactions neutrons and protons can be identical.

Comment: 1) I did not downvote your question 2) I am merely telling you some improvements you can make to the question 3) You should be adding the LINKS to the question, so that if some moderator comes by and deletes the comments, it will stay. 4) Your question is worded in a way that somewhat attracts downvotes. 5) Nobody is claiming that isospin symmetry is exact, but we are trying to tell you that the symmetry characteristics is coming from there, since your question pertains to that. 6) It is not helpful to point out that nuclear physics is full of haphazard approximations; we all know that.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360206

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there is no symmetry requirement for the exchange of non-identical fermions, but isospin is a useful approximate symmetry because it is essentially a short-cut for describing the spin-dependent effects of the strong interaction for protons and neutrons or up and down quarks.
It turns out that when differences are small (e.g. the proton-neutron or $u-d$ mass difference), or irrelevant (e.g. the electric charge for strong interactions), then the wavefunctions that best describe strongly bound systems are those that are anti-symmetric in $p-n$ or $u-d$ exchange.

The important point is that the strong interaction is spin dependent, and it turns out that nucleons are more strongly bound when their spins are parallel than anti-parallel.  The effects of the proton-neutron mass and charge differences are less than these spin-dependent effects.
Since having the spins parallel is what we'd expect if two identical particles were antisymmetric in another way, inventing isospin is a useful way of explaining the deuteron without getting into the messy details of nuclear forces. (See ["Why is nuclear force spin dependent?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288357/145491) and ["Why doesn't the deuterium nucleus have spin 0?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153422/145491).)

The situation for baryons is similar. Assuming isospin symmetry helps explain the observed bound states, but ultimately this is a consequence of the small $u-d$ mass difference and the charge-independence and spin-dependence of QCD interactions (which are very hard to calculate).